# Dialogs from facebook sdk pause my unity3d game on android

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

This is my first post here.

I have a problem w facebook sdk for unity. I use version 7.8.0 and unity 5.3.4f1. The problem is, when any facebook dialog shows up, my android game pauses and the background music stops playing.

I've already tried to set Application.runInBackground to true, but it didn't help. I also pass null as second argument of FB.Init method.

Has anybody encountered this problem? Is this a limitation of unity or is there a walkaround? In Clash Royale there are the same facebook dialogs as in my game, but they don't pause the background music. But Supercell studio has its own game engine.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"In the editor, go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Player. The inspector pane will now change to show the player settings. Look for the option that says "Run In Background" and check it.